# Variables don't keep values when ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

PHP variables doesn't keep their values when AJAX loads a content.

**index.php** Here is my code in index.php:

```
<?php
    if (empty($_GET["j"])) {@$_GET["j"] = "en";}
    $lang = htmlspecialchars($_GET["j"]);
 
    if (empty($_GET["as"])) {@$_GET["as"] = "home";}
    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["as"]);
 
    require_once("/scripts/header.php");
    require("/scripts/languages.php");
?>

    <div id="page">
        <?php 
            if (file_exists("pages/".$page.".php")) {
                include("pages/".$page.".php");
            } 
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <nav>
        <a href="/cs/home" class="link">Domů</a>
        <a href="/en/contact" class="link">Kontakt</a>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="/scripts/loader.js"></script>
```

**.htaccess** I need the URL to be rewrited by this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?j=$1&as=$2 [QSA]
```

**languages.php** - There I have some languages variables which I need to use in loaded content by ajax in #page div

```
<?php
    if ($lang== "cs") {
        $headline = "This is title in another language";
        $text = "
            <p>This is long text in another language.</p>
            <p>This is second paragraph in another language.</p>
        ";
    }
    else {
        $headline = "This is title";
        $text = "
            <p>This is long text.</p>
            <p>This is second paragraph.</p>
        ";
    }
?>
```

**loader.js** - Ajax loader:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav a.link').click(ChangePage);
});
 
function ChangePage() {
    var Link = $(this).attr('href');
    var Page = Link.substring(4);
    var Lang= Link.substring(1, 3);
    var Path = "/pages/" + Page+ ".php";
    
    $.ajax({
        url: Path,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            $("#page").html(result);
            document.title = $('#page_wrap').data('title');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("there is some error");
        }
    });
    
    return false;
}
```

**home.php** - I have this files like home, contact etc. which I need to load into #page div

```
<div id="page_wrap" data-title="Home - Site Name">HOME</div>
<?php 
    echo "
        <br>This is lang: ".$lang."
        <br>Headline: ".$headline."
        <br>Text: ".$text."
    "; 
?>
```

If I load page for first time it works. After I load content by clicking on nav link the variable of $lang is undefined.. How can I fix it please? I've even tried php session, but it didn't work at all. Is there any way how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like you're not passing those values into your ajax call, so it won't exist. Remember that PHP runs **before** the page is sent to the browser, and javascript **after**, and any subsequent calls from ajax won't have access to the PHP variables of the originating page.

Comment: You're doing an AJAX POST but I think you want to do a GET.

Comment: The Ajax post has nothing to do with the PHP... the $_GET vars come from the url, the PHP runs before JS so you can pass variables from PHP to JS but not the other way around. PHP cannot receive data from the page after it has been loaded without a new load of the page with new data either in the URL or as POST.

Comment: AJAX GET doesn't work too.. So there is no way how to load values of variables in language.php? I have value of page in var Page and value of language in var Lang. It doesn't matter for me, if I will reaload the page for changing language, but I do not know how to make variables in language.php works.

Comment: As I could analyze ur code, you are not echoing out anything from `language.php`, what is expected in `result` variable?, and `echo "
        <br>This is lang: ".$lang."
        <br>Headline: ".$headline."
        <br>Text: ".$text."
    "; ` this won't work as the variables are set in some other php and u are accessing it in some other file.

Comment: which PHP are you sending the AJAX request to? Index.php, or home.php? Also, remember that each request you send to your PHP is _separate_ and that variables from other scripts, or other executions of the same script, do not exist in any new request.

Comment: Using code like `include("pages/".$page.".php");` is opening yourself for possible exploits if you don't check/validate/sanitize the user's input